# Understanding which Series and Item an AutoCursor has snapped to in Lightningchart JS?

Tags: lightningchart

I have added two OHLCSeries to my chart. And the AutoCursor snaps between them. What event should I be listening to in order to capture when the AutoCursor has snapped to a new target? How do I figure out which of my two Series is being targeted? How do I figure out which item in my original dataset is being targeted (the dataset I added to the series using the add function)? Thanks

[image]

Comment: As you found out, there isn't an event for this purpose. Would be interested in learning more of the motivations behind it, as in what is done with the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty, but I found a solution here:
https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0703-customHTMLCursor.html?isList=true

```
  chart.onSeriesBackgroundMouseMove((_, event) => {
        // Get mouse location
        const mouseLocationClient = {
              x: event.clientX,
              y: event.clientY,
        };

        // Translate mouse location to coordinate system for solving data points from series, and translating to Axes.
        const mouseLocationEngine = chartL.engine.clientLocation2Engine(
              mouseLocationClient.x,
              mouseLocationClient.y,
        );

        // Translate mouse location to X Axis.
        const mouseLocationAxisX = translatePoint(mouseLocationEngine, dashboard.engine.scale, {
          x: chartL.getDefaultAxisX(),
          y: chartL.getDefaultAxisY(),
        }).x;

        // Use mouseLocationAxisX to match with index in your original data sets
  });
```